# Where is the field exclude checkbox in Content type > Manage display in Drupal 7

Tags: entities

When editing a content type in Drupal 6, in *"Display fields"*, there was a checkbox to "exclude" field (not just a dropdown for hidden).

Is there something like this for Drupal 7?

Answer (score 4):

Clicking and dragging the 4-arrow handle, you can move the field (which one you want to exclude) under "Hidden" (In Drupal 8 this is now called "Disabled".) in admin/structure/types/manage/{content type name}/display.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: thanks! as i understand though this simply 'hides' it, the content though will still render, or is that not so?